# NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1202

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I hit the login server, I get this error message:

> NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1202.

I have added App transport security in my Plist and I have allowed all the invalid certificates to YES.

Comment: You should add your code to make everybody able to help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acc to Google Search -1202 = NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted:

#### Help Links:

1. [HTTPS with NSURLConnection - NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578121/https-with-nsurlconnection-nsurlerrorservercertificateuntrusted)
2. [NSURLConnection Error code (-1202,1012)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494971/nsurlconnection-error-code-1202-1012)

#### REF : [Undocumented NSURLErrorDomain error codes (-1001, -1003 and -1004) using StoreKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778167/undocumented-nsurlerrordomain-error-codes-1001-1003-and-1004-using-storeki)

**Check validity of certificate in server side also, as this can be one possibility for this error**.

Also, `NSURLConnection` is depecrated i suggest update it via `NSURLSession`